# What currencies does Electrum support?

Tags: electrum

The [Bitcoin-Wiki page for Electrum](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Electrum) says it's a Bitcoin wallet.

However, there is also a Litecoin version.

What currencies does Electrum support?

Comment: Where does it say there is a lightcoin version?

Comment: https://electrum-ltc.org/

Comment: I am using it now

Comment: Oh, it's maintained by someone else besides Thomas who maintains Electrum.

Answer (score 5):

Electrum (http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/index.html) only supports Bitcoin.

There is an Electrum clone (https://electrum-ltc.org/) that supports Litecoin.

Comment: Anything like electrum for ethereum?

Comment: My friend uses https://www.myetherwallet.com/, and I use https://jaxx.io/.

Comment: @JimThio: For questions about Ethereum, please note that they have brought up their own SE: [ethereum.stackexchange.com](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

DASH: Digital Cash (https://www.dash.org/) also supports Electrum Wallet (it has it's own clone).
http://electrum.dash.org/